# Is there an official rule, or a generally accepted one, for how closely your validation data should match your training data?

Tags: validation, train

I'm finding myself making a gut-feeling judgment more and more often on whether the validation of my model is "close enough" to the modeled results from my training data.  I don't recall having ever seen a rule of thumb or guiding principle on how to navigate this problem so I'm using 10%; if my trained model has an R^2 of .70 then I would consider my model to be a valid model (lots of other considerations are taken for model validity) if the validation data has an R^2 of >=.63, for example. I'm looking for either official guidance or generally accepted principles.

Comment: the answer is obviously no, unless you're in a regulated industry, such as farma. in this case you need to ask elders. they'll know which rule or law is applicable

Comment: There really should not be such a rule anyway.  The difference between training and validation error is not a measure of overfitting.  For example, a correctly fit random forest should generally have close to zero training error.

Comment: I appreciate the comments so far but I'm afraid part of my question might have been taken [a lot] too literally.  I obviously don't mean a legally binding rule, I'm curious about generally accepted thoughts on the topic.  

Also, I'm not fitting a random forest model.  It's a linear regression model. I don't consider my experience to be all-inclusive by any means but I've never once fit a model with zero error between the training & validation set. Lastly, maybe we shouldn't say validation is a "measure" but it can absolutely be used to identify whether a model is overfit (or is garbage).